# Differentiation of a Square root

Tags: derivatives

Can the following be differentiated using first principles or the power rule?

$$y = (x^3+6x^2+3x-10)^{0.5}$$

I know I have to get it into an expression where each term on the right hand side has its own power, instead of the whole thing having a power; but get stuck there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $y'(x) = \dfrac{3 x^2+12 x+3}{2 \sqrt{x^3+6 x^2+3 x-10}}$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: $d/dx \left(f(x)^{1/2}\right) = 1/2 ~ \left(f(x)\right)^{-1/2}~f'(x)$

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation is also useful. $\ln y = \dfrac 12 \ln(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)$, $\dfrac {y'}y =\dfrac 12  \dfrac{3x^2 + 12x + 3}{x^3+6x^2+3x-10}$, $y' = \dfrac y2  \dfrac{3x^2 + 12x + 3}{x^3+6x^2+3x-10} = \dfrac{3 x^2+12 x+3}{2 \sqrt{x^3+6 x^2+3 x-10}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take the root out of the RHS by squaring both sides of the equation.

$$
\begin{align}
y
&=
(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)^\frac{1}{2} \\
y^2
&=x^3+6x^2+3x-10
\end{align}$$

Now differentiate to obtain
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)
&=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+6x^2+3x-10) \\
2y\frac{dy}{dx}
&= (3x^2+12x+3) \\
y'=\frac{dy}{dx}
&=\frac{3x^2+12x+3}{2y}=\frac{3x^2+12x+3}{2\left(x^3+6x^2+3x-10\right)^\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @GoodChessPlayer: Note that this method (implicit differentiation) is in fact one way we can easily prove that $\frac{d}{dx}( \sqrt{x} ) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. With not too much difficulty you can also get $\frac{d}{dx}( x^r ) = r x^{r-1}$ for any $x > 0$ and rational $r$. Beyond this you will need some more advanced real analysis to obtain the same rule for all real $r$. Anyway it is of course good to remember the result so that you don't have to rederive it every time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you use power rule and chain rule.

$ y' = \frac{1}{2}(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d}{dx}\left((x^3+6x^2+3x-10)\right) = \dfrac{3x^2+12x+3}{2(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)^\frac{1}{2}} $

Answer (score 1):

it is by the power rule $$\frac{1}{2}(x^3+6x^2+3x-1)^{-1/2}(3x^2+12x+3)$$ and the chain rule

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*} y &=\sqrt{x^3+6x^2+3x-10} \\ \quad \quad  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &=\frac{\mathrm{d}{(\sqrt{x^3+6x^2+3x-10})}}{\mathrm{d}x} \\ &=\frac{\mathrm{d}{(\sqrt{x^3+6x^2+3x-10})}}{\mathrm{d}{(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}{(x^3+6x^2+3x-10)}}{\mathrm{d}x} \\ &=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^3+6x^2+3x-10}} \cdot (3x^2+12x+3) \\ &=\frac{3x^2+12x+3}{2\sqrt{x^3+6x^2+3x-10}} \end{align*}$$

Comment: Using which rules do you calculate this? And do those rules explain the factor two that suddenly appears?

Comment: @hkBst I used the chain rule and the rule of polynomial differentiation (i.e. the power rule).